# How to make `return` respecting async/await in JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to make this code (a class method) returning a `String`.

```
async sign() {
    const txt = 'ddddd';
    const result = await crypto.createHash('md5').update(txt, 'binary').digest('hex');
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that it ignores `await` and returns a `Promise`. This function's returned value is used as a HTTP request header, and while npmlog says it's

```
apisign: Promise { 'faaa3f1409977cbcd4ac50b5f7cd81ec' }
```

in network traffic caught by Wireshark I see

```
apisign: [object Promise]
```

How do I make `return` respecting `await`, or how should I write it so it returns a `String`?

Comment: `async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}`

something like this?

Comment: oh, I just forgot to use `await` for header construction method. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should not return the value of an `async function` as is, since it is a `Promise`

`await` for it before serializing it.

Answer (score 1):

An [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Syntax).

If you invoke `sign()` inside another function then you have to `await` for it and this requires making the caller function also an `async` function and so on and so forth.

Eventually, at the top-level code you have to use the regular `.then().catch()` syntax to wait for the Promise to settle:

```
sign()
    .then((result) => {
        // do something with the result (e.g. put it into the response header)
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        // something wrong happened and the Promise was rejected
        // handle the error
        console.log(`There was an error: ${err.message || err}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `await` the response of a `async` function.

```js
const getURL = (title, page) => `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=${title}&page=${page}`


const callService = async (title, page) => {
  let response = await fetch(getURL(title, page));
  return await response.json();
}

async function callApi() {
  let data = await callService('spiderman', 1);
  console.log(data.data.length);
}

callApi();
```